# Como definir uma imagem no background da página?

Tags: css, background

Estou tentando rodar meu projeto com uma imagem de fundo da seguinte forma:

**A imagem está no caminho:**
webapp/resources/libimagens/bg.png

**O arquivo CSS está no caminho:**
webapp/resources/libcss/estilo.css

Dentro da tag `body{}` nas CSS eu já fiz da maneira abaixo, mas não funcionou.

`background-image: url(../libimagens/bg.png)`

Agradeço a quem dispor solução.

Comment: Acho que te enganas-te a escrever o caminho do arquivo CSS :P

Comment: Desculpa, realmente digitei errado. o caminho correto do CSS é:
"webapp/resources/libcss/estilo.css" - já editei.

Comment: Não tem problema na CSS. Está chamando o arquivo CSS na página html que irá utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 2):

**Se o arquivo CSS está no caminho:**
`webapp/resources/styles.css`

**E a imagem está no caminho:**
`webapp/resources/libimagens/bg.png`

O caminho correto para a propriedade `background-image` será:

```
background-image: url(libimagens/bg.png);
```

---

Ao usares - `background-image: url(../libimagens/bg.png)`, estás a voltar uma pasta para trás.

Os caminhos:

- A começar por "`/`" retorna para o diretório raiz e começa a partir daí
- A começar por "`../`" volta um diretório para trás e começa a partir daí
- A começar por "`../../`" volta dois diretórios para trás e começa a partir daí
- (e por aí em diante ...)
- Para avançar/mover para a frente, basta começar com o primeiro subdiretório e seguir em frente
  (`background-image: url(libimagens/bg.png);`)

<sub>[mais info](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)</sub>

Comment: Eu já tinha usado dessa forma, mas não tinha funcionado. Então eu vi em outro post que eu deveria usar "../" para voltar um diretório diretório, pois pra mim isso se aplicaria, já que a imagem está em outra pasta imediatamente anterior.
Eu uso o diretório resource para chamar o conteudo dela como library no JSF.
Tem outra maneira?

Comment: @Luiz , bom isso é estranho! Pois ele então deveria estar a funcionar. Já fizes-te o upload da imagem para esse diretório? Verifica também se não existe nenhum erro de digitação no caminho para a imagem. No final de teres feito e verificado isto e a imagem ainda assim não funcionar, utiliza o caminho absoluto para a imagem, que deverá ser algo como - `background-image: url(/webapp/resources/libimagens/bg.png);`, assumindo que `webapp` é a pasta raiz.

Answer (score 2):

Usar `../`, deveria estar funcionando, tente usar aspas dessa forma:

`background-image: url("../libimagens/bg.png")`, acredito que vai resolver.

Mas uma outra solução bem simples é usar o caminho absoluto para a imagem, por exemplo:

`background-image: url(http://www.urldoseusite.com/libimagens/bg.png)`

Comment: Na verdade isso é indiferente, ambas as maneiras (com o uso ou não de aspas) funcionam, é apenas uma questão de preferências. Sim, esse caminho deveria estar a funcionar.

Comment: @Lucas Muller, eu tentei tbm com aspas e com o caminho completo dessa forma. `url(/webapp/resources/libimagens/bg.png);`, só não usei link do site porque ainda não está em produção.

Encontrei, porém, a solução usando EL dentro da url funcionou:
`body{
   background-image: url("#{resource['libimagens/bg.png']}");
 }`

Stach em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/how-to-reference-jsf-image-resource-as-css-background-image-url/6926193#6926193

Obrigado.